# Hosting django on aks behind nginx-ingress

Tags: django, azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I am trying to host a django website on Azure kubernetes service behide nginx-ingress, and I would like my django web show under a path.

e.g. when access the default admin site, I would like to access it at `http://example.com/django/admin` instead of `http://example.com/admin`

I tried the configure below, when I access `http://example.com/django/admin` it will forward me to `http://example.com/admin` and show me 404 error from default ingress backend, as I set django debug to ture I assume this mean ingress did not send my request to my django service

```
# path example
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: django-ingress
  labels:
    app: django
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: django-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /django(/|$)(.*)
```

so I try to `curl -I -k http://example.com/django/admin`, and it show something like below

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: openresty/1.15.8.2
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2019 04:14:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: /admin/
```

The same thing happen to any valid page in the site, if I `curl -I -k http://example.com/django/any_valid_page` it show below:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: openresty/1.15.8.2
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2019 04:14:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: /any_valid_page/
```

I wonder it is caused by I am doing the test with the default django development web server? (i.e. `python manage.py runserver`)

If I try to host it at root like below, everything is fine...

```
# root example
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: django-ingress
  labels:
    app: django
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: django-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding this

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: django-ingress
  labels:
    app: django
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /django
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: django-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /django
```

Comment: Tried to add `rewrite-target` annotation and it act the same as my `root example` which everything fine under `http://example.com/` but I am trying to serve under `http://example.com/django/`, did I missed anything?

Comment: updated answer please check now and let me know if it's not work.

Comment: It did not change the url and return 404

Comment: @Bill `http://example.com/django/` open this url and check what response come.

Comment: This will return 404 from django

Comment: now check your service is running or not.Or ingress controller.

Comment: Yes, both running. As I set `DEBUG=True` in django, so the debug 404 page confirmed the ingress did route the access to django service. From my understand, what cause the issue is, when I access `/django/any_valid_page`, my configure in `path example` did forward it to `/any_valid_page` of my service but what django return in the header is a `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` follow by `Location: /any_valid_page/`, so it hit ingress again with `/any_valid_page` alone, and as it is no longer under `/django` and become a invalid page at the end

Answer (score 0):

> Starting in Version 0.22.0, ingress definitions using the annotation
>   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target are not backwards
>   compatible with previous versions. In Version 0.22.0 and beyond, any
>   substrings within the request URI that need to be passed to the
>   rewritten path must explicitly be defined in a capture group. So make
>   sure you have right version.

When using SSL offloading outside of cluster it may be useful to enforce a redirect to HTTPS even when there is no TLS certificate available. This can be achieved by using the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"` annotation in the particular resource.

I think your Ingress configuration file should look like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: django-ingress
  labels:
    app: django
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /django(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: django-service
              servicePort: 80
```

If you get 404 error, there is possible solution:

Please change  `https`  to  `http`  in the curl command?:

`curl --resolve your-host:80:xx.xxx.xx.xxx http://my-host:80`

To get the IP from `kubectl get ing` command, it is necessary to
enable the reporting Ingress status feature. Take a look on: [reporting-ingress-status](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/report-ingress-status.md).

There is the default server in the Ingress controller. It returns
the **Not Found** page with the **404** status code for all requests for
domains for which there are no Ingress rules defined. Those requests
are not shown in the access log.

Since you're getting a **404**, this means that the host header of your
requests doesn't match with the host field in the Ingress resource.
To set the host header in curl, please see  previous curl
commands. Optionally, you can also do:

```
curl http://<ip> -H "host: example.com"
```

Please take a look on [ngnix-ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/), [server-side-https-enforcement-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect).

Comment: The result is same as my `path example`, `/` return django 404, `/valid_path` return default backend 404

Comment: Thanks for input, but I am not quite sure what you want me to do with the edit (try the 2 curl command?)

Comment: and some update on my problem, I have tried to add code to set  [FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#force-script-name) to `/django ` and it seem to be work with the ingress configure `path example`, but it don't seem right to me, I suppose it is the problem of django development server and I need to use something else? I also tried to add header `X-Script-Name` and it don't work as well

Comment: I have workaround the issue with the `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` mentioned above, but it is something implemented in the applicate which I have no idea is it the right way to go as it look like something to do with either web server and/or ingress, still looking for input for this topic

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem from Django's side. Whenever the admin is not logged in, the `/django/admin` results in a redirect to `/admin/`. In this case, if you just replace `/django/admin/` with `/django/admin/` in the browser URL field it will work and open django admin login.

So basically Django's built-in redirect conflicts with the Ingress's rewrite module.